# Создание собственных событий своего компонента в GWT

Tags: gwt, java

Написан компонент "MyPanel extends VerticalPanel". Хочу добавить к нему событие, скажем, 'onDataAdded'/

Код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
MyPanel p = new MyPanel();
p.on('onDataAdded', new MyPanelDataAddedFunciton(){
  private void execute(int dataAddedCount) {
     alert("" + dataAddedCount);    
  }
});
```

или

```
MyPanel p = new MyPanel(){
   private void onDataAdded(int dataAddedCount) {
      alert("" + dataAddedCount);    
   }
});
```

Как это сделать? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Подобные схемы обработки уже давно не принято делать.

Первый вариант совершенно ужасен, второй - просто плох.

Для обработки событий есть довольно общепринятый паттерн. Принято делать интерфейс слушателя событий

```
public interface MyControlListener {
    void onDataChanged(int dataAddedCount);
}
```

Сам контрол должен иметь список обработчиков:

```
public class MyControl /*...*/ {
    private ArrayList<MyControlListener> listeners = new ArrayList<MyControlListener>();

    public void addListener(MyControlListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(MyControlListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private void fireListeners(int count) {
        for(MyControlListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onDataChanged(count);
        }
    }
/* ...... код может вызывать fireListeners(count) когда требуется уведомить слушателей */
}
```

После этого, все, кто заинтересован в этом событии могут подписаться на ивент, например, так:

```
class MyController implements MyControlListener {
    public void myInitMethod() {
        MyControl ctl = new MyControl();
        ctl.addListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(int count) {
        // тра-ла-ла
    }
}
```

Это общий best practice и применяется уже почти везде и всюду. Да посмотрите, хотя бы, на то, что уже есть, на то, как существующие ивенты сделаны.

Comment: А можно самый простенький работающий пример показать. Так вроде идея немного понятна, но с примером было бы супер!

Answer (score 3):

Я бы отнаследовался от GwtEvent (посмотрите примеры с ScrollEvent, AttachEvent, ValueChangeEvent, и другие) - допустим DataAddedEvent, а также DataAddedHandler (отнаследованный от EventHandler). Еще создайте has-handlers для него:

```
public interface HasDataAddedHandlers extends HasHandlers {
  HandlerRegistration addDataAddedHandler(DataAddedHandler handler);
}
```

Этот интерфейс и следует реализовать в вашей MyPanel. Такая схема дает преимущество, что вы можете вызывать ваше события, через один и тот же механизм, что и остальные events в gwt, используя addHandler класса Widget (начиная с gwt-2.1):

```
public final <H extends EventHandler> HandlerRegistration addHandler(
       final H handler, GwtEvent.Type<H> type)
```

И использовать HandlerRegistration для удаления слушателя, как принято в GWT (не нужно методов типа removeListener). А также не нужен fireEvent, т.к. событие генерируется из HandlerManager, нужно только реализовать в вашем классе DataAddedEvent метод

```
protected abstract void dispatch(H handler)
```

Именно такая схема принята в Gwt-2.1, которая немного отличается от традиционного MVC, но не принципиально